# Image not showing Stack Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stack

I Want show Image above the Container Using Stack Widget but I don't Know how to do
I'm Tried Position and Align Widget it's Work but image half Image Not visible

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:navami/Controller/FirebaseController.dart';
import 'package:navami/env.dart';

import '../DatabaseServices/dbServices.dart';
import 'wallet.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageId;
  final Map data;
  DetailScreen(this.imageId, this.data);
  final FirebaseController controller = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: imageId,
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 250,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          data['image'],
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              data['title'],
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue[600],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
 
            }));
  }
}
```

This is Emulator [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VBTz.png)
Screen Top 30 Padding after image and above the container then center of the container text
So I want this type of Screen

Answer (score 0):

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: h,
        width: w,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/welcome.png',
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10.0,
              child: Container(
                // height: h * 0.4,
                width: w,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    )),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 140,
                      width: 200,
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/Logoforstaicimage.svg',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Fitness is POWERFUL!! My mission is to bring people together, from all walks of life, with varying goals and abilities.",
                        textScaleFactor: 0.85,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                          color: Color(0xff76767c),
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          letterSpacing: 0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                     
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use this code working fine